# Python3 Print statement using .format() prints in reverse

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-cmd

I am trying to create a simple terminal-based game in Python 3. I'm using cmd module to make a menu, and within it I use a test script. Here's the code.

```
from assets import *
from cmd import Cmd
from test import TestFunction
import base64

class Grimdawn(Cmd):
#irrelevant code removed
    def do_test(self, args):
        """Run a test script. Requires dev password."""
        password = str(base64.b64decode("""REDACTED"""))
        if len(args) == 0:
            print("Please enter the password for accessing the test script.")
        elif args == password:
            test_args = input('Enter test command.\n')
            try:
                TestFunction(test_args.upper())
            except IndexError:
                print('Enter a command.')
                
        else:
            print("Incorrect password.")
```

The test function goes as follows.

#### edit: the basecharacter is different because I'm just now testing a new print format, didn't edit the other if statements yet

```
from assets import *
def TestFunction(args):
    player1 = BaseCharacter()
    player2 = BerserkerCharacter('Jon', 'Snow')
    player3 = WarriorCharacter('John', 'Smith')
    player4 = ArcherCharacter('Alexandra', 'Bobampkins')
    #//removed irrelevant code
    if args == "BASE_OFFENSE":
        return('Base Character: Offensive\n-------------------------\n{}'.format(player1.show_player_stats("offensive")))
    #. . .
    elif args == "ARCHER_OFFENSE":
        print('Archer Character: Offensive\n-------------------------\n{}'.format(player4.show_player_stats("offensive")))
        return
    #. . .
```

It should print `Archer Character: Offensive`, followed by a line, followed by the formatted code. But when I print it, this is the terminal output.

```
Joshua Brenneman - Grimdawn v0.0.2 |
> test *PASSWORD REDACTED*
Enter test command.
ARCHER_OFFENSE
Strength: 14.25
Agility: 10
Critical Chance: 50.0
Spell Power: 15
Intellect: 5
Speed: 6.25
Archer Character: Offensive
-------------------------
None
>
```

My end goal is for the print to show under the dashed line. If you're wondering, this is the print statement in the `assets.player` file.

```
def show_player_stats(self, category):
        #if the input for category is put into all upper case and it says "OFFENSIVE", do this
        if category.upper() == "OFFENSIVE":
            #print the stats. {} means a filler, and the .format makes it print the value based off the variables, in order; strength: {} will print strength: 15 if strength = 15
            print("Strength: {}\nAgility: {}\nCritical Chance: {}\nSpell Power: {}\nIntellect: {}\nSpeed: {}".format(self.strength, self.agility, self.criticalChance, self.spellPower, self.intellect, self.speed))
        #or, if the input for category is put into all upper case and it says "DEFENSIVE", do this
        elif category.upper() == "DEFENSIVE":
            #same as before
            print("Health: {}/{}\nStamina: {}\nArmor: {}\nResilience: {}".format(self.currentHealth, self.maxHealth, self.stamina, self.armor, self.resil))
        elif category.upper() == "INFO":
            print("Name: {} {}\nGold: {}\nClass: {}\nClass Description: {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name, self.gold, self.class_, self.desc))
        #if its anything else
        else:
            #raise an error, formating the Category {} with the category input given
            raise KeyError("Category {} is not a valid category! Please choose Offensive or Defensive.".format(category))
```

Am I missing something? I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `return` the string from `show_player_stats`, rather than printing it.

Comment: @L3viathan That was it! Thanks! Post as an answer and Ill mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's what L3viathan said. Your show_player_stats prints instead of returns. So your format statement is printing everything correctly, it just gets printed after show_player_stats prints its output.